# How to "derive" and interpret this data generating process for a high-dimensional VEC Model?

Tags: time-series, vector-autoregression, cointegration, vector-error-correction-model

I am currently trying to understand the following paper by [Smeekes & Wijler (2021)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0304407620302190) who are proposing an automated estimation procedure for models with a large number of potentially cointegrated variables.
I would say I have graduate level textbook knowledge on VAR models and VEC representations. However, I do not fully understand why they specify their data generation process the following way:

*Let $z_t = (y_t,x_t')$ be described by:*
$$z_t=\mu + \tau t + \zeta_t$$
*with the stochastic component given by:*
$$\Delta \zeta_t = AB'\zeta_{t-1}+\sum_{j=1}^{p}\Phi_j \Delta \zeta_{t-j} + \epsilon_t$$
*The model can be rewritten into a VECM form by substituting the first equation into the second:*
$$\Delta z_t= AB'(z_{t-1}-\mu -\tau (t-1))+\tau^*+\sum_{j=1}^{p}\Phi_j \Delta z_{t-j} + \epsilon_t$$
*where $\tau^* = (I-\sum_{j=1}^{p}\Phi_j)\tau$*

Now, my main problem is basically the understanding and interpretation of equation 1 and its link to equation 2 as I have never seen such a representation. To be more specific, it obviously does not look like a VAR, I do not understand why index t appears to be a variable in this model and lastly, why equation 2 (which is actually the standard VEC representation I used to know) is dependent on this "stochastic component" zeta.

I already did my own textbook research, including Hamilton, but could not find any satisfying answer yet. I would also be happy about any literature hints.

Thanks in advance!